# sale tax code (python) calculation

Tags: python

I have created a small program to get the purchase and add both the state tax and the country tax using only function 
the problem that I'm facing is how would I edit the program so it calculate the taxes and display them

```
def main():
    purchase1=float(input("Enter the purchase amount: "))

    return purchase1
def tax(purchase1):
    calculateTax=1.00+0.025+0.05
    return purchase1*calculateTax
def printResult(purchase1,total):
    print("Purchase amount",purchase1)
    print("State Tax Amount 2.5%")
    print("Country Tax Amount 5%")
    print("The Total tax amount is 7.5%")
    print("Your Total is :",format(total))
purchase1=main()
totalTax=tax(purchase1)
printResult(purchase1,totalTax)
```

I want to display the calculation of the taxe after the print statment (State Tax and Country Tax)

Comment: `print("Your Total is :",format(total))` is wrong. Do `print("Your Total is : {}".format(total))`

Comment: This seems to be working. What behavior were you expecting, and what behavior did you see instead?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Those two snippets will produce the same result.

Comment: I wanted the program to calculate the taxes separately printed it and then calculate both of then and display them and finally add them to the purchase

Comment: So, the only thing you want to add is a detailed breakdown of state and federal tax paid (I assume this is for some country outside the United States, as we don't have a federal sales tax)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def main():
    purchase1=float(input("Enter the purchase amount: "))

    return purchase1
def tax(purchase1):
    calculateTax=1.00+0.025+0.05
    return purchase1*calculateTax
def printResult(purchase1,total):
    print("Purchase amount",purchase1)
    print("State Tax Amount 2.5%", purchase1*0.025)
    print("Country Tax Amount 5%", purchase1*0.05)
    print("The Total tax amount is 7.5%", purchase1*0.075)
    print("Your Total is :",format(total))
purchase1=main()
totalTax=tax(purchase1)
printResult(purchase1,totalTax)
```